# Nginx - how to take value from header and set it into cookie?

Tags: tomcat, nginx, url-rewriting, session-cookies

On the nginx i need to check if client have jsessionid cookie, then proxy everything to tomcat as is, but if there are no cookie then take value from header x-auth-token and set it into jsessionid cookie, and after that proxy everything to tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
location / {
    if ($cookie_JSESSIONID = "") {
        add_header Set-Cookie JSESSIONID=$http_x_auth_token;
    }
    proxy_pass <proto://tomcat_server_address:port>;
}
```

If your tomcat domain is different from the site domain, you may need to add additional parameters before the `proxy_pass` parameter:

```
proxy_set_header Host <tomcat_domain>;
proxy_cookie_domain <tomcat_domain> <site_domain>;
```